# installing gazebo in a overlay

Tags: ros, gazebo, ros-fuerte, overlay

[image: Rosanswers logo]

hello, i trying to install a different version of gazebo like a overlay, i create my workspace and run the following lines:

```
rosws set --svn simulator_gazebo https://code.ros.org/svn/ros-pkg/stacks/simulator_gazebo/tags/simulator_gazebo-1.7.6
```

and the

```
rosws update
```

but i obtain this:

```
virtualtouch@ubuntu:~/fuerte_workspace$ rosws update 
[simulator_gazebo] Installing https://code.ros.org/svn/ros-pkg/stacks/simulator_gazebo/tags/simulator_gazebo-1.7.6 (version None) to /home/virtualtouch/fuerte_workspace/simulator_gazebo
svn: OPTIONS of 'https://code.ros.org/svn/ros-pkg/stacks/simulator_gazebo/tags/simulator_gazebo-1.7.6': could not connect to server (https://code.ros.org)
Exception caught during install: Error processing 'simulator_gazebo' : [simulator_gazebo] Checkout of https://code.ros.org/svn/ros-pkg/stacks/simulator_gazebo/tags/simulator_gazebo-1.7.6 version None into /home/virtualtouch/fuerte_workspace/simulator_gazebo failed.

ERROR in config: Error processing 'simulator_gazebo' : [simulator_gazebo] Checkout of https://code.ros.org/svn/ros-pkg/stacks/simulator_gazebo/tags/simulator_gazebo-1.7.6 version None into /home/virtualtouch/fuerte_workspace/simulator_gazebo failed.
```

i dont know if the url adress of the code is wrong, someone could help me?...

im working in ros fuerte with ubuntu 12.04

thank you!!

EDIT

it works, but when i run:

```
rosmake simulator_gazebo
```

i obtain this error:

> This code block was moved to the following github gist:
> https://gist.github.com/answers-se-migration-openrobotics/174693426ccf435cb0b6332298364eeb

Any idea???

EDIT:

Now i get this error:

```
root@ubuntu:~/fuerte_workspace/simulator_gazebo# rosmake
[ rosmake ] rosmake starting...                                                                                         
[ rosmake ] No package specified.  Building stack ['simulator_gazebo']                                                  
[ rosmake ] Packages requested are: ['simulator_gazebo']                                                                
[ rosmake ] Logging to directory /root/.ros/rosmake/rosmake_output-20130124-113525                                      
[ rosmake ] Expanded args ['simulator_gazebo'] to:
['gazebo_plugins', 'gazebo_tools', 'gazebo', 'gazebo_worlds', 'gazebo_msgs', 'gazebo_tests']
[rosmake-0] Starting >>> roslang [ make ]                                                                               
[rosmake-0] Finished <<< roslang  No Makefile in package roslang                                                        
[rosmake-0] Starting >>> roscpp [ make ]                                                                                
[rosmake-0] Finished <<< roscpp  No Makefile in package roscpp                                                          
[rosmake-0] Starting >>> urdf_interface [ make ]                                                                        
[rosmake-0] Finished <<< urdf_interface ROS_NOBUILD in package urdf_interface                                           
[rosmake-0] Starting >>> urdf_parser [ make ]                                                                           
[rosmake-0] Finished <<< urdf_parser ROS_NOBUILD in package urdf_parser                                                 
[rosmake-0] Starting >>> ivcon [ make ]                                                                                 
[rosmake-0] Finished <<< ivcon ROS_NOBUILD in package ivcon                                                             
[rosmake-0] Starting >>> common_rosdeps [ make ]                                                                        
[rosmake-0] Finished <<< common_rosdeps ROS_NOBUILD in package common_rosdeps                                           
[rosmake-0] Starting >>> ogre [ make ]                                                                                  
[rosmake-0] Finished <<< ogre ROS_NOBUILD in package ogre                                                               
[rosmake-0] Starting >>> colladadom [ make ]                                                                            
[rosmake-0] Finished <<< colladadom ROS_NOBUILD in package colladadom                                                   
[rosmake-0] Starting >>> collada_parser [ make ]                                                                        
[rosmake-0] Finished <<< collada_parser ROS_NOBUILD in package collada_parser                                           
[rosmake-0] Starting >>> urdf [ make ]                                                                                  
[rosmake-0] Finished <<< urdf ROS_NOBUILD in package urdf                                                               
[rosmake-0] Starting >>> rosconsole [ make ]                                                                            
[rosmake-0] Finished <<< rosconsole  No Makefile in package rosconsole                                                  
[rosmake-0] Starting >>> srdf [ make ]                                                                                  
[rosmake-0] Finished <<< srdf ROS_NOBUILD in package srdf                                                               
[rosmake-0] Starting >>> rosbuild [ make ]                                                                              
[rosmake-0] Finished <<< rosbuild  No Makefile in package rosbuild                                                      
[rosmake-0] Starting >>> roslib [ make ]                                                                                
[rosmake-0] Finished <<< roslib  No Makefile in package roslib                                                          
[rosmake-1] Starting >>> rospy [ make ]                                                                                 
[rosmake-2] Starting >>> pluginlib [ make ]                                                                             
[rosmake-0] Starting >>> bond [ make ]                                                                                  
[rosmake-3] Starting >>> smclib [ make ]                                                                                
[rosmake-1] Finished <<< rospy  No Makefile in package rospy                                                            
[rosmake-2] Finished <<< pluginlib ROS_NOBUILD in package pluginlib                                                     
[rosmake-0] Finished <<< bond ROS_NOBUILD in package bond                                                               
[rosmake-2] Starting >>> rosservice [ make ]                                                                            
[rosmake-1] Starting >>> message_filters [ make ]                                                                       
[rosmake-0] Starting >>> std_msgs [ make ]                                                                              
[rosmake-3] Finished <<< smclib ROS_NOBUILD in package smclib                                                           
[rosmake-1] Finished <<< message_filters  No Makefile in package message_filters                                        
[rosmake-2] Finished <<< rosservice  No Makefile in package rosservice                                                  
[rosmake-2] Starting >>> dynamic_reconfigure [ make ]                                                                   
[rosmake-1] Starting >>> resource_retriever [ make ]                                                                    
[rosmake-0] Finished <<< std_msgs  No Makefile in package std_msgs                                                      
[rosmake-3] Starting >>> bondcpp [ make ]                                                                               
[rosmake-0] Starting >>> angles [ make ]                                                                                
[rosmake-1] Finished <<< resource_retriever ROS_NOBUILD in package resource_retriever                                   
[rosmake-2] Finished <<< dynamic_reconfigure ROS_NOBUILD in package dynamic_reconfigure                                 
[rosmake-2] Starting >>> geometry_msgs [ make ]                                                                         
[rosmake-2] Finished <<< geometry_msgs  No Makefile in package geometry_msgs                                            
[rosmake-2] Starting >>> sensor_msgs [ make ]                                                                           
[rosmake-2] Finished <<< sensor_msgs  No Makefile in package sensor_msgs                                                
[rosmake-2] Starting >>> image_transport [ make ]                                                                       
[rosmake-2] Finished <<< image_transport ROS_NOBUILD in package image_transport                                         
[rosmake-0] Finished <<< angles ROS_NOBUILD in package angles                                                           
[rosmake-1] Starting >>> rosbag [ make ]                                                                                
[rosmake-2] Starting >>> polled_camera [ make ]                                                                         
[rosmake-2] Finished <<< polled_camera ROS_NOBUILD in package polled_camera                                             
[rosmake-3] Finished <<< bondcpp ROS_NOBUILD in package bondcpp                                                         
[rosmake-1] Finished <<< rosbag  No Makefile in package rosbag                                                          
[rosmake-0] Starting >>> collada_urdf [ make ]                                                                          
[rosmake-0] Finished <<< collada_urdf ROS_NOBUILD in package collada_urdf                                               
[rosmake-3] Starting >>> nodelet [ make ]                                                                               
[rosmake-3] Finished <<< nodelet ROS_NOBUILD in package nodelet                                                         
[rosmake-1] Starting >>> bullet [ make ]                                                                                
[rosmake-0] Starting >>> rostest [ make ]                                                                               
[rosmake-2] Starting >>> roswtf [ make ]                                                                                
[rosmake-3] Starting >>> nodelet_topic_tools [ make ]                                                                   
[rosmake-1] Finished <<< bullet ROS_NOBUILD in package bullet                                                           
[rosmake-3] Finished <<< nodelet_topic_tools ROS_NOBUILD in package nodelet_topic_tools                                 
[rosmake-1] Starting >>> convex_decomposition [ make ]                                                                  
[rosmake-1] Finished <<< convex_decomposition ROS_NOBUILD in package convex_decomposition                               
[rosmake-3] Starting >>> gazebo_msgs [ make ]                                                                           
[rosmake-1] Starting >>> std_srvs [ make ]                                                                              
[rosmake-0] Finished <<< rostest  No Makefile in package rostest                                                        
[rosmake-2] Finished <<< roswtf  No Makefile in package roswtf                                                          
[rosmake-1] Finished <<< std_srvs  No Makefile in package std_srvs                                                      
[rosmake-1] Starting >>> rosgraph_msgs [ make ]                                                                         
[rosmake-2] Starting >>> tf [ make ]                                                                                    
[rosmake-0] Starting >>> xacro [ make ]                                                                                 
[rosmake-1] Finished <<< rosgraph_msgs  No Makefile in package rosgraph_msgs                                            
[rosmake-2] Finished <<< tf ROS_NOBUILD in package tf                                                                   
[rosmake-2] Starting >>> pcl_ros [ make ]                                                                               
[rosmake-1] Starting >>> protobuf [ make ]                                                                              
[rosmake-0] Finished <<< xacro ROS_NOBUILD in package xacro                                                             
[rosmake-0] Starting >>> nav_msgs [ make ]                                                                              
[rosmake-2] Finished <<< pcl_ros ROS_NOBUILD in package pcl_ros                                                         
[rosmake-1] Finished <<< protobuf ROS_NOBUILD in package protobuf                                                       
[rosmake-2] Starting >>> diagnostic_msgs [ make ]                                                                       
[rosmake-1] Starting >>> orocos_kdl [ make ]                                                                            
[rosmake-0] Finished <<< nav_msgs  No Makefile in package nav_msgs                                                      
[rosmake-2] Finished <<< diagnostic_msgs  No Makefile in package diagnostic_msgs                                        
[rosmake-0] Starting >>> camera_calibration_parsers [ make ]                                                            
[rosmake-2] Starting >>> diagnostic_updater [ make ]                                                                    
[rosmake-1] Finished <<< orocos_kdl ROS_NOBUILD in package orocos_kdl                                                   
[rosmake-2] Finished <<< diagnostic_updater ROS_NOBUILD in package diagnostic_updater                                   
[rosmake-0] Finished <<< camera_calibration_parsers ROS_NOBUILD in package camera_calibration_parsers                   
[rosmake-0] Starting >>> simmechanics_to_urdf [ make ]                                                                  
[rosmake-2] Starting >>> self_test [ make ]                                                                             
[rosmake-0] Finished <<< simmechanics_to_urdf ROS_NOBUILD in package simmechanics_to_urdf                               
[rosmake-1] Starting >>> python_orocos_kdl [ make ]                                                                     
[rosmake-0] Starting >>> timestamp_tools [ make ]                                                                       
[rosmake-2] Finished <<< self_test ROS_NOBUILD in package self_test                                                     
[rosmake-2] Starting >>> driver_base [ make ]                                                                           
[rosmake-2] Finished <<< driver_base ROS_NOBUILD in package driver_base                                                 
[rosmake-2] Starting >>> test_nodelet [ make ]                                                                          
[rosmake-0] Finished <<< timestamp_tools ROS_NOBUILD in package timestamp_tools                                         
[rosmake-0] Starting >>> ogre_tools [ make ]                                                                            
[rosmake-1] Finished <<< python_orocos_kdl ROS_NOBUILD in package python_orocos_kdl                                     
[rosmake-2] Finished <<< test_nodelet ROS_NOBUILD in package test_nodelet                                               
[rosmake-2] Starting >>> camera_info_manager [ make ]                                                                   
[rosmake-1] Starting >>> kdl [ make ]                                                                                   
[rosmake-0] Finished <<< ogre_tools ROS_NOBUILD in package ogre_tools                                                   
[rosmake-2] Finished <<< camera_info_manager ROS_NOBUILD in package camera_info_manager                                 
[rosmake-1] Finished <<< kdl ROS_NOBUILD in package kdl
 No Makefile in package kdl                                     
[rosmake-2] Starting >>> eigen_conversions [ make ]                                                                     
[rosmake-1] Starting >>> tf_conversions [ make ]                                                                        
[rosmake-0] Starting >>> kdl_parser [ make ]                                                                            
[rosmake-0] Finished <<< kdl_parser ROS_NOBUILD in package kdl_parser                                                   
[rosmake-0] Starting >>> mk [ make ]                                                                                    
[rosmake-2] Finished <<< eigen_conversions ROS_NOBUILD in package eigen_conversions                                     
[rosmake-1] Finished <<< tf_conversions ROS_NOBUILD in package tf_conversions                                           
[rosmake-1] Starting >>> robot_state_publisher [ make ]                                                                 
[rosmake-0] Finished <<< mk  No Makefile in package mk                                                                  
[rosmake-1] Finished <<< robot_state_publisher ROS_NOBUILD in package robot_state_publisher                             
[rosmake-3] Finished <<< gazebo_msgs [PASS] [ 32.08 seconds ]                                                           
[rosmake-3] Starting >>> gazebo [ make ]                                                                                
[ rosmake ] Last 40 lineszebo: 906.0 sec ]                                                   [ 1 Active 63/68 Complete ]
{-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  touch wiped
  mkdir -p build
  if [ ! -f gazebo-r54c81cc8dd7c.tgz.md5sum ]; then echo "Error: Couldn't find md5sum file gazebo-r54c81cc8dd7c.tgz.md5sum" && false; fi
  `rospack find rosbuild`/bin/download_checkmd5.py https://code.ros.org/svn/release/download/thirdparty/gazebo/gazebo-r54c81cc8dd7c.tgz build/gazebo-r54c81cc8dd7c.tgz `awk {'print $1'} gazebo-r54c81cc8dd7c.tgz.md5sum`
  [rosbuild] Downloading https://code.ros.org/svn/release/download/thirdparty/gazebo/gazebo-r54c81cc8dd7c.tgz to build/gazebo-r54c81cc8dd7c.tgz...Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "/opt/ros/fuerte/share/ros/core/rosbuild/bin/download_checkmd5.py", line 56, in <module>
      sys.exit(main())
    File "/opt/ros/fuerte/share/ros/core/rosbuild/bin/download_checkmd5.py", line 28, in main
      urllib.urlretrieve(uri, dest)
    File "/usr/lib/python2.7/urllib.py", line 93, in urlretrieve
      return _urlopener.retrieve(url, filename, reporthook, data)
    File "/usr/lib/python2.7/urllib.py", line 239, in retrieve
      fp = self.open(url, data)
    File "/usr/lib/python2.7/urllib.py", line 207, in open
      return getattr(self, name)(url)
    File "/usr/lib/python2.7/urllib.py", line 436, in open_https
      h.endheaders(data)
    File "/usr/lib/python2.7/httplib.py", line 954, in endheaders
      self._send_output(message_body)
    File "/usr/lib/python2.7/httplib.py", line 814, in _send_output
      self.send(msg)
    File "/usr/lib/python2.7/httplib.py", line 776, in send
      self.connect()
    File "/usr/lib/python2.7/httplib.py", line 1161, in connect
      self.sock = ssl.wrap_socket(sock, self.key_file, self.cert_file)
    File "/usr/lib/python2.7/ssl.py", line 381, in wrap_socket
      ciphers=ciphers)
    File "/usr/lib/python2.7/ssl.py", line 143, in __init__
      self.do_handshake()
    File "/usr/lib/python2.7/ssl.py", line 305, in do_handshake
      self._sslobj.do_handshake()
  IOError: [Errno socket error] [Errno 8] _ssl.c:504: EOF occurred in violation of protocol
  make[1]: se sale del directorio «/root/fuerte_workspace/simulator_gazebo/gazebo»
  make[1]: *** [build/gazebo/unpacked] Error 1
  CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:21 (message):
    Build of Gazebo failed
  
  
  -- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------}
[ rosmake ] Output from build of package gazebo written to:
[ rosmake ]    /root/.ros/rosmake/rosmake_output-20130124-113525/gazebo/build_output.log
[rosmake-3] Finished <<< gazebo [FAIL] [ 906.04 seconds ]                                                               
[ rosmake ] Halting due to failure in package gazebo. 
[ rosmake ] Waiting for other threads to complete.               
[ rosmake ] Results:                                                                                                    
[ rosmake ] Built 64 packages with 1 failures.                                                                          
[ rosmake ] Summary output to directory                                                                                 
[ rosmake ] /root/.ros/rosmake/rosmake_output-20130124-113525
```

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/53150/installing-gazebo-in-a-overlay/) by [joseescobar60](https://answers.ros.org/users/3496/joseescobar60/) on ROS Answers with karma: 172 on 2013-01-23

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Your command is fine and it works for me. It looks like code.ros.org was down when you tried. Do you want to try again?

---

Originally posted by [piyushk](https://answers.ros.org/users/1770/piyushk/) with karma: 2871 on 2013-01-23

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0